# Choice of the appopriate conditional statement

Tags: microcontroller, c, programming, interrupts

I'm measuring the width of a PWM puls with the external interrupt:

```
void interrupt ISR() {

if (INTCON3bits.INT1IF) {                   // INT0 interrupt
    if(INTCON2bits.INTEDG1) {               // Rising edge detected
        T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;               // Start TMR1
        INTCON2bits.INTEDG1 = 0;            // Swap edge
    } else if (!INTCON2bits.INTEDG1) {      // Falling edge detected
        T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 0;               // Stop TMR1
        INTCON2bits.INTEDG1 = 1;            // Swap edge
    }
 INTCON3bits.INT1IF = 0;                    // Clear flag
    }
}
```

I want to store the width of the current pulse and the width of the next pulse. By width I mean the TMR1 value[hex], not a time value [s]. How and where should I do this?

Something else: If these two pulse values are the same I want to do 'something1', if they are not then I want to do 'something2': Looks like this:

```
if (current_value == previous_value) {
     Do something1; // if entered here, I will start UART communication and keep reading incomming data constantly, so I suppose this is a dead end.
 } else {
     Do something2; // if entered here, there is no need of pulse measurment anymore
 }
```

But while in this if routine I want constantly check for the pulse width, how can I do that? I thought of a do-while routine, but not sure about it too.

I'm working with pic18f25k80, using MPLAB X if this is important

Comment: Just an observation: the third if statement `(if (!INTCON2bits.INTEDG1)` is redundant. You can remove it and have exactly the same functionality.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't directly answering your questions, but addresses the higher level problem of measuring the width of a pulse using a typical PIC 16.

First, there is no point in starting and stopping a counter.  All you need to do is take a snapshot of the counter each edge, then do a integer subtract of the new value minus the previous value.  That will give you the elapsed counts between the two events up to the maximum counts the counter can express.  It doesn't matter whether the count value wrapped around during the interval, as long as the number of counts was within the counter's range.  The subtraction always yields the number of counts as a unsigned number.

For example, let's say you are using a 16 bit timer, such as timer 1 on a PIC 16.  The timer value is therefore always 0 to 65535.  As long as the interval you are trying to measure is 65535 ticks or less in length, a simple subtract of new minus previous will always result in the desired answer.  Let's say the interval is 100 ticks long.  Obviously this works if the previous and new counts are 1234 and 1334, 5000 and 5100, etc.

However, it still works even if the counter wrapped during the interval.  For example, consider what happens if the previous value was 65500, which is FFDCh.  Adding 100 (64h) to that yields 10040h.  However, the hardware just throws away the carry out of the last bit, so the 16 bit counter value will be 0040h (64).  So to determine the length of the inteval, you do the subtraction of 64 - 65500, or 0040h - FFDCh, or 0000000001000000b - 1111111110111100b, with only the low 16 bits of the result kept.  Work this out any way you want, and you will see the result is 100, 0064h, or 0000000001100100b.

The second point is that most of these PICs have hardware to do the capture operation you are currently doing in firmware.  Read the datasheet chapter on the CCP module again, this time paying particular attention to capture mode.  You will see that the CCP hardware grabs the free running timer 1 value at the time of a input edge.  It only does this on one edge polarity, so you still have to take the interrupt and switch to the other edge polarity to set up for the next capture event.  Or, if you have two CCP modules available, you set them to capture on opposite edges.  In either case, the timer 1 value is captured into the CCP registers for you by the hardware at the time of the edge.  All you have to do is grab it before the next edge and do the subtract to find the number of timer 1 ticks since the last capture event.  Timer 1 free runs the whole time.  Starting and stopping it would only waste cycles and possibly cause you miss events and add jitter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately all the CCP & ECCP modules that I have are already in use. But I'll see if I can work with a free running timer

Comment: +1  --  I've found that PICs with timer gating built in seem to be more apt for tasks such as these.  I have a go-to part in the 12F series for this, but haven't looked for one in the 16F line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save values from one function call to the next, you can declare a static variable:

```
void interrupt ISR()
{
  static int last_width = 0;
  int new_width;

  //Get the new width
  new_width = ...

  //After some processing, save the new width
  last_width = new_width;
}
```

last_width gets initialized once when your program starts up, just like a global variable. It then retains its value between calls to ISR().

Keep in mind that your measurement will not be very precise if the time it takes to get into the interrupt varies. This can happen if other interrupts are tying up the CPU.